# What are the differences between tokens generated by `aws-iam-authenticator` and `aws eks get-token` when authenticate to kubernetes-dashboard?

Tags: amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

`kubectl` is using `aws eks get-token` and works perfectly.

But when I try to login to [kubernetes-dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) with the token generated below I get `Unauthorized (401): Invalid credentials provided`:

```
AWS_PROFILE=MYPROFILE aws eks get-token --cluster-name myclustername | jq -r '.status.token'
```

But if I use the token generated with:

```
AWS_PROFILE=MYPROFILE aws-iam-authenticator -i myclustername token --token-only
```

then I can login to kubernetes-dashboard.

So in which way are those tokens different? I thought they were equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be not difference between the tokens generated by `aws-iam-authenticator` or `aws eks get-token`.

Make sure that you spelled  the cluster name right in both commands as **you can generate tokens for clusters that do not exist**.

Double check that both commands authenticate:

```
kubectl --token=`AWS_PROFILE=MYPROFILE aws-iam-authenticator -i MYCLUSTERNAME  token --token-only` get nodes
kubectl --token=`AWS_PROFILE=MYPROFILE aws --region eu-north-1 eks get-token --cluster-name MYCLUSTERNAME | jq -r '.status.token'` get nodes
```

Sometimes is very easy to misspell the cluster name and the tools will happily generate a token for it without producing any visible error or warning.